# success method is not calling after hitting the service in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

below is the code im using to send the value to service, the value is successfully sending to server and saved in db. but success method is not get called in ajax.

```
$("#addRemarkBtn").click(function() {
    debugger;
    var remark=$("#enterRemark").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: serviceurl+remark,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("sucess");
        },
        fail: function() {
            console.log("failed");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: did it worked after using edited code?

Comment: erros in the browser console?

Comment: what are you returning in response?

Comment: no. i did not get any error in browser

Comment: try user error instead of fail for your error callback and see if you get an error?

Comment: i did't change any thing. but, it is working fine now.